# How to find out if a (windows) memory-mapped-file already exists, using python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, mmap, memory-mapped-files

In Win32, the textbook solution to determine whether a resource already exists is: create it and check if GetLastError() returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.

For example:

```
HANDLE h = ::CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, size, name);  
bool alreadyExists = (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
```

In python, the mmap module wraps memory-mapped-files.

But the following code:

```
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1  
m = mmap.mmap(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, length=size, tagname=name)  
print ctypes.get_last_error()
```

always prints 0, even if the (named) mmap already exists.

Is there a simple way to emulate the above C/Win32 code in python?

Answer (score 2):

you can use ctypes 
for example:

```
import ctypes
def check_file_is_mapped_file(file_name,file_size):
    _CreateFileMapping = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateFileMappingW
    _GetLastError = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1 #from msdn
    PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04 #from msdn
    ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS = 0xB7 #from msdn
    h =_CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,0,PAGE_READWRITE,0,file_size, ctypes.c_wchar_p(file_name))
    return (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) and (_GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
```